# Create a list of latest datetimes in a range of dates PANDAS PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that reads from a .csv file. The dataframe has two columns, 'timestamp' and 'users_holding'. The 'timestamp' column has multiple datetimes for each day, and the 'users_holding' column shows the amount of users holding a stock at the corresponding datetime. How would I create a list of datetimes that is made up of the last datetime entry of each day

input

```
'2020-01-01 01:55', '2020-01-01 02:34', '2020-01-01 23:55', '2020-01-02 01:34', '2020-01-02, 02:40', '2020-01-02 22:54'
```

output

```
'2020-01-01 23:55', '2020-01-02 22:54'
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set your datetime column and create a new one as index:

```
df['start_timestamp_index'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start_timestamp)
df = df.set_index('start_timestamp_index')
```

Then,

```
last_of_each_day = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month, df.index.day]).last()['start_timestamp'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. it's not clear if times you want to exclude are a list or a continuous range.  If it was a range I would have used `between()`
2. have used `isin()` to find rows.  BTW your list contains duplicates.  I used `unique() only to check my answer
3. then exclude identified rows from `agg()` grouping by the day `floor("D")`

Your excluded rows are before end of day so will make no difference ....

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import random
t = list(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,1,1), dt.datetime(2020,1,3), freq='min'))
uh = [random.randint(0,50) for e in t]
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp":t, "user_holding":uh})

exc = ['2020-01-01 01:55', '2020-01-01 02:34', '2020-01-01 23:55', '2020-01-02 01:34', 
       '2020-01-02 02:40', '2020-01-02 22:54', '2020-01-01 23:55', '2020-01-02 22:54']
# best to work with timestamps not strings
exc = pd.to_datetime(exc).sort_values().unique().tolist()
# good practice define mask
mask = df["timestamp"].isin(exc)
# exclude masked row then get last value
df.loc[~mask].groupby(df["timestamp"].dt.floor("D")).agg({"timestamp":"last","user_holding":"last"})
```

**output**

```
            timestamp           user_holding
timestamp       
2020-01-01  2020-01-01 23:59:00 0
2020-01-02  2020-01-02 23:59:00 32
2020-01-03  2020-01-03 00:00:00 20
```